# Google Drive API cant download file with files.get, request or google request

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, xmlhttprequest, cors

Im using the client-side js Google Drive API and i cant seem to read/download a text file created earlier by the same api.

I tried files.get, manual requests and google request, on both the files/fileID and webContentLink urls.

webContentLink works if i open it in browser but not thru request, even tho I'm authorized in browser (cookie present) and sending the token in request (both url and header).

```
fileId
wcLink = webContentLink
oToken = oauthToken
```

Test1

Google request on webContentLink

returns 404 not found

calls [https://drive.google.com/static/proxy.html?usegapi=1&jsh=m;/*/scs/apps-static/*/js/k=oz.gapi.en.jw7XZHvcak8.O/am=wQE/d=1/ct=zgms/rs=AGLTcCOXtLG11kt9d673FzpjO_GiLUGIQA/m=**features**](https://drive.google.com/static/proxy.html?usegapi=1&jsh=m;/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.en.jw7XZHvcak8.O/am=wQE/d=1/ct=zgms/rs=AGLTcCOXtLG11kt9d673FzpjO_GiLUGIQA/m=__features__)

```
let r = gapi.client.request({
    'path': wcLink,
    'method': 'GET',
    'params': {'fileId': fileId, 'alt': 'media'},
    'headers': {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + oToken }
})
r.execute((response,rawData)=>{ //callback not called at all
    console.log('resp',response)
    console.log('raw',rawData)
})
```

Test2

Google request on files/fileId, using .execute

returns 200 OK, response undefined and raw has empty body, content-length 0

```
let r = gapi.client.request({
    'path': 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/'+fileId,
    'method': 'GET',
    'params': {'fileId': fileId, 'alt': 'media'},
    'headers': {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + oToken }
})
r.execute((response,rawData)=>{
    console.log('resp',response) //undefined
    console.log('raw',rawData) //body:'', content-length:0
})
```

Test3

drive.files.get on fileId

returns 200 OK, response result: false, body: ''

```
gapi.client.drive.files.get({
    'fileId': fileId,
    'alt': 'media'
})
.then((response,rawData)=>{
    console.log('resp',response) //result: false, body: ''
    console.log('raw',rawData) //undefined
})
```

Test4

Google request on files/fileId, using .then

returns 200 OK, response result: false, body: ''

```
gapi.client.request({
    'path': 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/'+fileId,
    'method': 'GET',
    'params': {'fileId': fileId, 'alt': 'media'},
    'headers': {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + oToken }
})
.then((response,rawData)=>{
    console.log('resp',response) //result: false, body: ''
    console.log('raw',rawData) //undefined
})
```

Test5

http request on files/fileId

returns 403 forbidden, CORS warning

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET',
'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/' + fileId +
'?alt=media&access_token=' + encodeURIComponent(oToken), true)
xhr.responseType = "blob"
xhr.onreadystatechange = ()=>{
    console.log('readyStateChange',xhr)
}
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + oToken)
xhr.send()
```

Test6

http request on webContentLink with access token in link

returns 401 Unauthorized, CORS warning

```
let reqUrl = wcLink + '&access_token=' + encodeURIComponent(oToken)
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhr.open("GET", reqUrl, true)
xhr.responseType = "blob"
xhr.onreadystatechange = ()=>{
    console.log('readyStateChange',xhr)
}
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + oToken)
xhr.send()
```

Test7

http request on webContentLink without access token in link, no responseType

I dont understand how this differs from the above example where i pass access_token in both url and header and get 401 unathorized yet here i pass i only header and get 200 ok...

returns 200 OK, CORS warning

```
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhr.onreadystatechange = ()=>{
  console.log('response',xhr)
}
xhr.open('GET', wcLink, true)
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + oToken)
xhr.send()
```

Whole responses: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0aHK.png) [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22rZZ.png), in networking tab: [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ejBC.png)

Comment: The image at https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ejBC.png shows some responses are 401, 403 and 404 errors. For 4xx errors, it’s normal and expected that the error won’t have the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header. That’s because most servers by default only send a minimal set of headers in 4xx responses. To include additional headers in error responses, some non-default option typically must be set. But even if those 4xx errors did have the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header, they’d still be 4xx errors that need fixing. They’re not “blocked by CORS” — they’re just errors.

Comment: @sideshowbarker Ok but they still dont have a reason to happen, im still passing in the access token in both the url, the header and i got the cookie that im logged in... why would i be getting Unauthorized and Forbidden?

Comment: Have you tried using the `files: get` [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get)? Do you still get the same result? Are you setting your field parameter to get content other than the default `kind`, `id,` `name,` and `mimeType`?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo im using files.get to get the webContentLink thats used in these tests, and im using files.get with 'alt': 'media' like described for [downloading](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads) in the Docs, in Test3.

Comment: [webContentLink isn't for use with the API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#viewing_files_in_a_browser), only for Browser downloads, which you said in your question was the case. For using the API you _must_ use the fileID. The authorisation you need to use comes from the client credentials provided by your GCP project. Follow the [Google Drive API Quickstart for JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/js) and adapt it to use the files.get method.

Comment: @RafaGuillermo as i said, i already tried the files.get method as described in the docs (Test3) in my previous comment.

And i am providing the access_token both thru url, headers and the cookie (since i am in the browser).

Comment: @LukaKostic Are you sure your text file has the correct metadata and has content? Can you post the code which you used to create said file? I uploaded a txt file to Drive from my local machine and ran [this function](https://pastebin.com/rUw5zPp6) which allowed me to see the body in the reponse, containing the content of the file as expected.

Comment: @RafaGuillermo i create the file with gapi.client.drive.files.create with  resource: { name: 'pboard.pb', body: '<JSON text here>', mimeType: 'text/plain' }

Comment: Now that i check the file its empty, so that probably thats it.. Ill add some content manually and see if it returns correctly

Comment: Posted that as answer, thanks @RafaGuillermo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems my upload code wasn't working properly and was creating an empty file.

Ive manually added content to it and its now correctly being retrieved in bodies of tests 2 (in raw), 3 (in response) and 4 (in response)